# PHP preg_replace - replacing characters between special characters

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm a beginner in PHP. 
And would need help in resolving the following issue.

This is the the original string

```
/hs/?page_id=27&file=filename.jpg
```

And i would like it to be replaced with the following.

```
/hs/wp-content/gallery/filename.jpg
```

And please note that the filename and id number are subjected to change everytime.
So i guess use of wildcards could be a better choice to replace the characters between "?" and "=" .

How could this be accomplished with the use of reg_replace ?
Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to replace characters between `?` and `=` is to use the `.*` regular expression part, which will match "anything, repeated any number of times"

```
$result = preg_replace('[/hs/\?.*=]', '/hs/wp-content/gallery/', $input);
```

---

A more general solution, if you want to extract the `file=` component of any input URL, even if the parameters are in a different order, would be:

```
$result = preg_replace('[.*file=([^&]*).*]', '/hs/wp-content/gallery/\1', $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP `parse_url` and `parse_str` functions can be used if you want to avoid regex:

```
$url= '/hs/?page_id=27&file=filename.jpg';
$parsed = parse_url($url); 
parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);

$new_url = $parsed['path'] . 'wp-content/gallery/' . $query['file'];
```

**[Ideone demo.](http://ideone.com/NlVhSE)**